# How to open keyboard in editText?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, android-keypad

I have screen with listview, when I click on an item I replace the Textview with EditText by showing & hiding. I am able to hide the TextView & visible the EditText. But after getting EditText visible, it is not showing soft keyboard like in normal behavior.  I have tried other answer to display keyboard programmatically, but nothing worked at all.

This is my list.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/settings_list_item"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Setting" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover_holo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/settingTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/white_smoke"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/settings_list_item"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
        android:text="@string/settings_item_1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSelfDestroyCount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="@string/selfDestoryCount"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/masterPasswordOption"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/master_password"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code to hide the textView & display the editText.

```
case 3:
{
    TextView textView = ( TextView ) view.findViewById( R.id.txtItemName );
    textView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    ImageView imageView = ( ImageView ) view.findViewById( R.id.rightArrow );
    imageView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    final EditText editText = ( EditText ) view.findViewById( R.id.txtSelfDestroyCount );
    editText.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode( true);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            System.out.println ( "clicked " );
            // Set keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            // Lets soft keyboard trigger only if no physical keyboard present
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        }
    });     

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

When I click on the EditText, I  can see `System.out.println ( "clicked " );` on DDMS.

Please help me.

Comment: You shouldn't have to handle the onClick event for the EditText, Android should inflate the keyboard by default. Try getting rid of your `editText.setOnClickListener(...`

Comment: @zgc7009, I tried, but nothing worked.

Comment: Could you post your Manifest? Maybe you need to change this property inside the Activity tags: 

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`

Comment: @LuisLavieri I tried that part already too, but it didnt worked at all

Answer (score 0):

Change this property of your edit text and it should display the soft keyboard:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type this property in your `Activity tags` inside your `manifest`

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`

More about this property [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

**Example**:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >
```

Answer (score 0):

In an application I use this code block :

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```